# Is Webassembly supported in Firefox on iOS?

Tags: ios, firefox, webassembly

It doesn't list it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly#Browser_compatibility

or here:
https://caniuse.com/#search=webassembly

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have to use the system browser engine on iOS, so the "Safari for iOS" line applies for all of them.